# In Taxonomy View, how do I get the count of relationships associated with that term

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

In a View based on a Taxonomy Term, is there a field which shows a count of how many relationships that tag has?

I'm pulling a list of Academic Years in this situation. If there is no Nodes tagged with these years, I'd like to omit them from the list.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this two ways:

1. You can create a view of nodes, create a relationship to their taxonomy term, and display the terms. This will only display terms that can be pulled up through a node by views.
2. You can keep your taxonomy display and add a relationship. Add "Taxonomy: content with term" and the check the box labeled "Require this relationship". This will give you duplicates so you also need to go down to "Query Settings" and check the box for "Distinct".

Comment: I forgot to mention that if you want to display a count of nodes under each taxonomy term, option one will do that. Option two won't, by default.

Comment: Good to know, but I just needed to not show taxo terms without associated content. This was great.